# How to add custom button to DispForm

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am attempting to add a label, text box and a button to dispform page.  The purpose is for a user looking at a list entry to add a comment.  Upon clicking on the button, the text they entered will update another list.

Is is possible to do this and how?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to thank you for your suggestion.  What I ended up doing was something quite similar to the steps given on The SharePoint Dive for customizing list forms.  You can find the steps here:

http://thesharepointdive.wordpress.com/2012/03/20/list-forms-deployment-for-sharepoint-2010-part-1-of-4/

It was a bit more work than your suggestions may have been but fit my requirements quite well and something I can easily re-use in other solutions.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, but you have to make aspx control to display form and add some C# /VB code behind it. OR u can add button in conteneditor webpart, open editform in background, add to the hidden field some value f.g some string with listname etc. and then with JS save "edit form" and all your code will be executed by eventreciever "ItemEdited" :) its hard but possible to do. Last option is to make your own solution, or DisplayWebPartForm.

all of those solutions is Hard to Code, but i dont see other options, becouse u have to execute C#/VB on the server or client side